# Having no error when acking message failed

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

Sometimes, about 1 of 10000 rabbit acks I have problem with acking properly.

In scenario with failure when I am acking `message A` I got no exception. Seems like everything went ok. When I enqueue next `message B` I am getting exception `System.IO.EndOfStreamException: SharedQueue`. Stack trace says that exception was thrown in `RabbitMQ.Util.SharedQueue.EnsureIsOpen()` which is private method.

There is a problem - `A message` is not acked! I got no exception when acking, but it is still not acked! There is a small chance that two application can get the same message. Is there anything I can do about it?

I already tried to change some settings like:

```
AutomaticRecoveryEnabled = true;
RequestedHeartbeat = 60;
NetworkRecoveryInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
```

And wrote a method to test connection before every ack:

```
public bool HasFullConnection() {
    if (!HasServerConnection(Config.ConnectionConfig.HostAddress)) return false;
    if (!RabbitMQConnection.IsOpen) return false;
    if (!RabbitMQClient.IsOpen) return false;

    return true;
}
```

Unfortunelly - problem still exists.

Comment: It is very helpful to let us know what is in your broker's log file.

Answer (score 1):

So, there are a couple of things going on here. First, as you've probably found out by now, the C# client library doesn't handle off-nominal situations very well.  Second, and more importantly, your application design requires 100% reliability on `ack`ing, which it should not.

A failure rate of 1 in 10,000 (or 0.01%) is reasonably good. If you're only seeing `ack` failures on 0.01% of your messages, I would consider that to be an acceptable level of failure. Acknowledgements in RabbitMQ are delivered to the broker asynchronously, and are based on the channel and consumer that originally received the message. Many things can happen between the time a message was received and when it was actually acknowledged. Thus, if anything happens which disrupts the consumer, channel, broker, or connection, the message is assumed to have failed and is re-delivered.

This is known as *at least once delivery*. The alternative to this is *at most once delivery* (the alternate does not use acknowledgements).  So, your system should be designed to handle redelivered messages, assuming you're using at most once delivery.

Comment: I can't afford redeliver message if it thought it was acked successfully. Is there any way to check if connection with rabbit still exist? `RabbitMQ.Util.SharedQueue.EnsureIsOpen()` seems to be a way, but for some reason this method is private. I need a synchronous method to check connection state. This could limit my problems with acking. I could just check if connection is ok, and then do the job. I am acking at most 5 messages/sec, so this would not be a big performance loss.

Comment: No, and it seems by your comment that you have a fairly serious design issue. Can you provide additional details or explanation as to why a repeat message is the end of the world?